# Capture Image On Android

Tags: android

I am trying to capture Image on android and display it on an image view;
the capture intent called when the activity starts ,and image view is in the same activity that calls the capture Intent 
when i run the application the camera **capture the Image TWICE then display the image in Image view ?!** any ideas why ? and how can i fix it?

**> Activity.java**

```
public class View extends Activity{
    ImageView imgview;
    Bitmap Bmp;
    final static int cameraData = 0;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.camera);
        imgview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgview);
        Intent i = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        startActivityForResult(i, cameraData);


    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            Bmp = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
            imgview.setImageBitmap(Bmp);    }


    }}
```

**> camera.xml**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:opencv="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:contentDescription="Image view"
         android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
      />

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm starring at your code and can't see anything, that looks familiar to what I except from a camera application.

Here's the guide to [Camera Apps](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#capture-picture)

At a glance, you do the following:

1. You get a `Camera` instance and a `CameraPreview` (a `FrameLayout`) and put the preview into your layout.
2. For capturing an image (whatever triggers this in your application) you use `Camera.takePicture()`.
3. This in turn calls `onPictureTaken()` of the `PictureCallback`. Within `onPictureTaken()` you get the file containing the image data with `getOutputMediaFile()`.
4. Copy it and have fun with the data.

Answer (score 0):

you better call `startActivityForResult()` upon an event(say a button click for eg).

Instead of calling directly form `onCreate()` , add a button and start camera intent inside button click.

Comment: Thanks , but i want to capture images without specifying any events

Answer (score 0):

Basically just a guess but I think your activities onCreate method is also called after the camera took the first picture(!?) try something like

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.camera);
    imgview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgview);

    if(!getIntent.hasExtra("data")){
        Intent i = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(i, cameraData);
    }
}
```

I'm not very sure about this and can't test something right now(no sdks installed over here) but I hope it helps!